# ASP.NET DropDownList not set to the selected item in async call

Tags: drop-down-menu, asynchronous, selecteditem

I am using VS 2010 (framework 4.0) for website development along with rad/telerik controls.  The scenario is I have radwindow popup, actually a confirmation message box.  On the basis of decision I have to call the base page again where have to call respective function.  Here I want to set Country dropdownlist and state dropdowlist. I call the server side event in javascript function on OnClientClose event of Radwindow and in server side function call respective functions to set the form fields where I set Country and State list as well. But when I try to set Country selected value, it not get selected though there are items in dropdownlist. Here is the code,

Javascript function

```
function OnradWndConfirmSelfOwnerClose(oWnd) {
            var hdn = document.getElementById("<%= hdnIsOwner.ClientID %>");
            try {
                var arg = oWnd.argument;
                if (arg == "YES") {
                    hdn.value = 'true';
                }
                else {
                    hdn.value = 'false';
                }
                __doPostBack('<%=this.btnInitializeOwnerForm.UniqueID %>', '');
            }
            catch (err) { }
        }
```

Server side function,

```
protected void btnInitializeOwnerForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool IsOwner = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnIsOwner.Value) ? Convert.ToBoolean(hdnIsOwner.Value) : false;
            if (IsOwner)
            {
                SaveOwner();
            }
            else
            {
                InitializeOwnerData();
            }
        }
```

and in InitializeOwnerData() there is call for SetDefaultFields() function,

```
private void SetDefaultFields(ApplicationAccessInfo objAAInfo)
        {
            //Set Company Information fields
            txtOrganizationName.Text = objAAInfo.EntityorOrganization;
            txtCompanyWebsite.Text = objAAInfo.CompanyWebsite;
            txtStreetAddress.Text = objAAInfo.StreetAddrees;
            txtOfficeNumber.Text = objAAInfo.SuiteorOfficeNumber;
            txtCity.Text = objAAInfo.City;

            if (Guid.Empty != objAAInfo.CompanyCountryId)
            {
                **ddlCountry.Items.FindByValue(objAAInfo.CompanyCountryId.ToString()).Selected = true;**
                PopulateStateList();
                if (ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
                    **ddlState.Items.FindByValue(objAAInfo.CompanyStateId.ToString()).Selected = true;**
            }

            txtPostalCode.Text = objAAInfo.PostalCode;

            //Disable Company Information fields
            txtCompanyWebsite.Enabled = false;
            txtOrganizationName.Enabled = false;
            txtStreetAddress.Enabled = false;
            txtOfficeNumber.Enabled = false;
            txtCity.Enabled = false;
            txtPostalCode.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false;
            ddlState.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Item not get selected at ddlCountry.Items.FindByValue(objAAInfo.CompanyCountryId.ToString()).Selected = true
so ultimately gets error on,
ddlState.Items.FindByValue(objAAInfo.CompanyStateId.ToString()).Selected = true;

Note that when I call this same function normally then all works perfectly.  In this scenario I found Items in Country list and objAAInfo.CompanyCountryId is also in the list.

Please help me out of this